# Can not log in with unit test in django-allauth

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-allauth

I've tried to test my views with unittest like this

```
class TestClassroomView(TestCase):

def test_classroom_view(self):
    auth_headers = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode('test@tst.com:test')}
    response = self.client.get('/classroom/3/', follow=True, **auth_headers)
    self.assertContains(response, 'Course progress')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

And this:

```
class TestClassroomView(TestCase):
 def test_classroom(self):
    self.client.login(username='test@tst.com', password='test')
    response = self.client.get('/classroom/3/', follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'web/dashboard.html')
```

`response.redirect_chain` always shows this

`[('http://testserver/?next=/classroom/3/', 302)]`

If I leave only `status_code` checks then tests passing, but actually they test nothing.
I'm using django-allauth authentication system
Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

Also how can I load fixtures on test start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what helped me with authentication

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 

class TestParent(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    username = 'testuser'
    password = 'testpass'
    User = get_user_model()
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, password=password)
    logged_in = self.client.login(username=username, password=password)
    self.assertTrue(logged_in)
```